# Tesseract & OpenCV - Processing Image

Tags: opencv, ocr, tesseract

I"m trying to process this chalkboard image I recorded with tesseract, but am having no luck. I thought about doing pre-processing to help improve our results but am unsure of what methods to call on it.

Here is the image I have:

[image]

And here are the `tesseract` commands I'm running:

```
convert 468.jpg  -bordercolor black -border 20x20 468-b.jpg
tesseract 468-b.jpg - -psm 11
```

Please note it doesn't have to process all the math symbols correctly, but at least get the `1 + 4 = 5` and maybe the `2 x 12 = 24 x 1`.

I had a previous photo that worked well with using just these commands. Here's the photo:

[image]

And here are the results it would spit out:

```
I+I

2+2m
```

It's not perfect, but it was much better than what I was getting before. How can I improve the results of my new chalkboard image? Do I need to use OpenCV, and if so, an example implementation would be very, very helpful

Thanks in advance

P.S. Here was my original question I asked on [Tesseracts GitHub](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract) that lead me to better results:

https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/468

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tesseract cannot recognize handwriting image well. So I think you should use deep learning for recognizing handwriting image.

Here is some tutorial you interest in.

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/tutorials/mnist/beginners/index.html#mnist-for-ml-beginners

Comment: also [this](http://www.juergenwiki.de/notes/machine_learning_reading_in_mnist_dataset.html) maybe helpful